# Плагин Monitor-Hibernate для GeoServer 2.16.x

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, обновление, gis

Добился сборки monitor-hibernate для версии GeoServer 2.15.x и 2.16.x
https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/tree/master/src/community/monitor-hibernate

Поднял версию

```
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3
```

до

```
org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.
```

Убрал из

```
 new HibernateCallback<List<RequestData>>() {
                public List<RequestData> doInHibernate(Session session)
                        throws HibernateException, SQLException {
```

эксепшен

```
 SQLException
```

согласно разнице в доках
https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateCallback
и
https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateCallback

Плагин собрался, тесты прошли, но при попытке подключить плагин в GeoServer он падает с ошибкой:

> 2020-02-11 15:34:14,187 WARN [geoserver.monitor] - monitoring storage memory not found, falling back to 'memory'
>   ...
>   2020-02-11 15:34:14,555 WARN [support.XmlWebApplicationContext] - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'wmtsCapabilitiesProvider' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Tomcat%209.0/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gs-gwc-2.16.2.jar!/applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'geoServer' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'geoServer' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Tomcat%209.0/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gs-main-2.16.2.jar!/applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'catalog' while setting bean property 'catalog'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'localWorkspaceCatalog' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Tomcat%209.0/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gs-main-2.16.2.jar!/applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'advertisedCatalog' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'advertisedCatalog' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Tomcat%209.0/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gs-main-2.16.2.jar!/applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'secureCatalog' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'secureCatalog' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Tomcat%209.0/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gs-main-2.16.2.jar!/applicationContext.xml]: Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.geoserver.security.SecureCatalogImpl]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
>   2020-02-11 15:34:14,561 ERROR [context.ContextLoader] - Context initialization failed
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'wmtsCapabilitiesProvider' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Tomcat%209.0/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gs-gwc-2.16.2.jar!/applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'geoServer' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'geoServer' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Tomcat%209.0/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gs-main-2.16.2.jar!/applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'catalog' while setting bean property 'catalog'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'localWorkspaceCatalog' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Tomcat%209.0/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gs-main-2.16.2.jar!/applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'advertisedCatalog' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'advertisedCatalog' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Tomcat%209.0/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gs-main-2.16.2.jar!/applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'secureCatalog' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'secureCatalog' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Tomcat%209.0/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gs-main-2.16.2.jar!/applicationContext.xml]: Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.geoserver.security.SecureCatalogImpl]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:378)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:110)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:674)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:188)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1308)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1154)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:846)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:863)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546)
>       at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:400)
>       at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:291)
>       at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103)
>       at org.geoserver.platform.GeoServerContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(GeoServerContextLoaderListener.java:22)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4685)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5146)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:717)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:690)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:705)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:978)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1849)
>       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
>       at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:773)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:427)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1576)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:309)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:423)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:366)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:936)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:841)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
>       at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:421)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:932)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:633)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:344)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:475)
>   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'geoServer' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Tomcat%209.0/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gs-main-2.16.2.jar!/applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'catalog' while setting bean property 'catalog'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'localWorkspaceCatalog' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Tomcat%209.0/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gs-main-2.16.2.jar!/applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'advertisedCatalog' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'advertisedCatalog' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Tomcat%209.0/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gs-main-2.16.2.jar!/applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'secureCatalog' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'secureCatalog' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Tomcat%209.0/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gs-main-2.16.2.jar!/applicationContext.xml]: Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.geoserver.security.SecureCatalogImpl]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:378)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:110)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1648)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1400)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:575)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:367)
>       ... 59 more
>   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'localWorkspaceCatalog' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Tomcat%209.0/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gs-main-2.16.2.jar!/applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'advertisedCatalog' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'advertisedCatalog' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Tomcat%209.0/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gs-main-2.16.2.jar!/applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'secureCatalog' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'secureCatalog' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Tomcat%209.0/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gs-main-2.16.2.jar!/applicationContext.xml]: Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.geoserver.security.SecureCatalogImpl]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:378)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:110)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:674)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:188)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1308)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1154)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:367)
>       ... 69 more
>   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'advertisedCatalog' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Tomcat%209.0/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gs-main-2.16.2.jar!/applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'secureCatalog' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'secureCatalog' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Tomcat%209.0/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gs-main-2.16.2.jar!/applicationContext.xml]: Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.geoserver.security.SecureCatalogImpl]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:378)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:110)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:674)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:188)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1308)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1154)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:367)
>       ... 81 more
>   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'secureCatalog' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Tomcat%209.0/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gs-main-2.16.2.jar!/applicationContext.xml]: Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.geoserver.security.SecureCatalogImpl]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:303)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:284)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1308)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1154)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:367)
>       ... 93 more
>   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.geoserver.security.SecureCatalogImpl]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:184)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:117)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:299)
>       ... 103 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at org.geoserver.security.impl.DefaultResourceAccessManager.buildAuthorizationTree(DefaultResourceAccessManager.java:342)
>       at org.geoserver.security.impl.DefaultResourceAccessManager.(DefaultResourceAccessManager.java:124)
>       at org.geoserver.security.SecureCatalogImpl.buildDefaultResourceAccessManager(SecureCatalogImpl.java:116)
>       at org.geoserver.security.SecureCatalogImpl.lookupResourceAccessManager(SecureCatalogImpl.java:106)
>       at org.geoserver.security.SecureCatalogImpl.(SecureCatalogImpl.java:92)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>       at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:172)
>       ... 105 more

Ошибка вроде бы вообще в другом месте возникает, но только при подключении этого плагина...

Что ему ещё нужно, что бы завестись?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нет смысла мучиться с данной проблемой - проще написать плагин заново:

http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/Error-Monitor-Extension-td5309208.html